# Gdiplus::Bitmap freeing memory

Tags: bitmap, gdi+

The following is my code (thanks to someone else) of reading an image file and returning a Gdiplus::Bitmap. My question is is the code (at the bottom) correct in creating the Bitmap (it seems to work) and  in the calling code when I'm done with the Bitmap can I just call delete pBitmap;

Thanks in advance

```
HRESULT ImageUtilities::LoadImageFromFile(
   std::string path,
   UINT destinationWidth,
   UINT destinationHeight,
   UINT frame,
   Gdiplus::Bitmap **ppBitmap,
   double *resX,
   double *resY)
{
   CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> pSource;
   CComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> pDecoder;
   CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> pConverter;
   CComPtr<IWICBitmapScaler> pScaler;

   // get image factory
   IWICImagingFactory *pImageFactory = WICImagingFactory::GetInstance().GetFactory();

   // get / determine image decoder
   HRESULT hr = pImageFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename( MultiByteToUnicode(path).c_str(), NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &pDecoder );

   // get the specified frame from the image
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      // Validate the given frame index nFrame
      UINT nCount = 0;
      // Get the number of frames in this image
      if (SUCCEEDED(pDecoder->GetFrameCount(&nCount)))
      {
         if (frame >= nCount)
            frame = nCount - 1; // If the requested frame number is too big, default to the last frame
      }

      // get the frame
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
         hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
      }
   }

   // get the image converter
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      // Convert the image format to 32bppPBGRA (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM + D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
      hr = pImageFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      pSource->GetResolution(resX, resY);
      // if a new width or height was specified, create an IWICBitmapScaler and use it to resize the image
      if (destinationWidth != 0 || destinationHeight != 0)
      {
         UINT originalWidth, originalHeight;
         hr = pSource->GetSize(&originalWidth, &originalHeight);
         if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
         {
            if (destinationWidth == 0)
            {
               FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationHeight) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight);
               destinationWidth = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth));
            }
            else if (destinationHeight == 0)
            {
               FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationWidth) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth);
               destinationHeight = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight));
            }

            hr = pImageFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
               hr = pScaler->Initialize(pSource, destinationWidth, destinationHeight, WICBitmapInterpolationModeCubic);
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
               hr = pConverter->Initialize(pScaler, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                  NULL,
                  0.f,
                  WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
                  );
            }
         }
      }
      else // Don't scale the image.
      {
         hr = pConverter->Initialize(pSource, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.f,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
            );
      }
   }

   // finally create a GDI+ Bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      // calculate stride and necessary buffer size
      UINT uWidth, uHeight;
      hr = pConverter->GetSize(&uWidth, &uHeight);
      const UINT cbStride = 4 * uWidth;
      const UINT cbBufferSize = cbStride * uHeight;

      // allocate buffer then copy pixels
      // NOTE: we are responable to delete this buffer when we delete the Bitmap
      BYTE *pBitmapBuffer = new BYTE[cbBufferSize];

      WICRect rc;
      rc.X = 0; rc.Y = 0; rc.Width = uWidth; rc.Height = uHeight;
      hr = pConverter->CopyPixels(&rc, cbStride, cbBufferSize, (BYTE *)pBitmapBuffer);

      // create a Gdiplus::Bitmap object
      Gdiplus::Bitmap *pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(uWidth, uHeight, cbStride,
         PixelFormat32bppPARGB, pBitmapBuffer);

      delete[] pBitmapBuffer;

      if (Gdiplus::Ok != pBitmap->GetLastStatus())
      {
         return E_FAIL;
      }

      *ppBitmap = pBitmap;
   }

   return hr;
}
```

I changed the above to the following and things seem to be running better

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap *pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(uWidth, uHeight, PixelFormat32bppPARGB);

      Gdiplus::BitmapData bd;
      Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, pBitmap->GetWidth(), pBitmap->GetHeight());
      Gdiplus::Status status = pBitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeWrite, PixelFormat32bppPARGB, &bd);
      if (Gdiplus::Ok == status)
      {
         memcpy(bd.Scan0, pBitmapBuffer, cbStride*uHeight);
         status = pBitmap->UnlockBits(&bd);
      }


      delete[] pBitmapBuffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory management looks correct to me. If you do not pass a data pointer to the Bitmap constructor (or you pass it a NULL pointer), you are not responsible for freeing the image data.

It's not a good idea to assume the stride of the new Bitmap object is what you expect. In this case, I think it will work out, but if you change the pixel format to something that isn't 4 bytes in size, GDI+ may add some padding to the rows. To do this cleanly, you should read the stride from the BitmapData and copy each row individually.

You could also do the CopyPixels call while the Bitmap is locked, using the Scan0 from BitmapData directly, and not allocate an intermediate buffer.